# Trying to write script for time zone difference

Tags: bash, shell

I'm new to linux scripting, just wanted to write a script to automate the time zone different.

What i'm solving for:

- Search the two time field called "a" and "b" from a given file
- find the difference  between them "c=b-a"
- And assign the time zone accordingly:

  - if "c" is between 04:00:00 to 05:00:00 then echo "Newyork"
  - elseif "c" is between 05:00:00 to 06:00:00 then echo "Chicago"
  - elseif "c" is between 06:00:00 to 07:00:00 then echo "Denver"

**The real scenario:**

This my file:

```
DEBUG   2017-09csssss-03 01:03:47,956 logging_user=LOCAL SERVICE,
windows_event_id=2105, windows_user_name=LOCAL SERVICE, [**create_dt=
07:09:33**][1], syslog_parser_LogHeaderType=SYSLOG_3164_0,
destination_host_name=WREMOTE029QPG.xxxxx.COM,
log_acceptor_protocol=UDP,
windows_event_source=Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode,
option56=Well Known Group, log_acceptor_port=514,
syslog_severityText=INFO, vendor_severity=1,
windows_computer_name=WREMOTE029QPG.xxxxx.COM, event_ct=1,
machine_ip=192.168.0.200, target_resource=LOCAL SERVICE,
windows_event_record_number=3542, proxy_machine_ip=192.168.157.1,
proxy_machine_port=49333, LoggingProtocol=SYSLOG_SERVER,
reporting_sensor=Sensor_onbox_UDP_514,
windows_source_eventlog=Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode/Operational,
[**event_dt=02:09:30**][2], user_name=LOCAL SERVICE,
log_acceptor_type=SYSLOG_SERVER,
logging_device_name=WREMOTE029QPG.xxxxx.COM, category_id=30007601,
source_host_name=WREMOTE029QPG.xxxxx.COM,
EventClassName=symc_windows_eventlog,parse severity=1, 


  [1]: http://value%201   [2]: http://value%202
```

From the above file, I'm trying to find the timezone.

Search the value for `"event_dt"=` and `"create_dt="` and find the difference as below

`timezone = 07:09:33 - 02:09:30 = 05:00:03` like that

if "timezone" is between 04:00:00 to 05:00:00 then echo "New york"

elseif "if "c" is between 05:00:00 to 06:00:00 then echo "Chicago"

Finally output should be : Chicago

I've been trying this for last one week, but no luck.

Please help me on this:)

Answer (score 0):

Bash is not an ideal solution for something like this. The string parsing capabilities of Bash are rudimentary at best. It can be done, but would be quite complicated, especially if the text you are parsing is not standardized. Problems like this are precisely why Larry Wall invented Perl. So, in Perl you could try something like this (not tested for robustness):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open( my $fh, "<", "f.txt") or die "cannot open file: $!\n";
my $line = <$fh>;
close($fh);

my @fields = split(',', $line);

foreach my $elm (@fields) {
    if ($elm =~ /create_dt=(.*)/) {
        $created = $1;
        $created =~ s/ *//;
    }
    if ($elm =~ /event_dt=(.*)/) {
        $event = $1;
        $event =~ s/ *//;
    }
}

my @ctimes = split(':', $created);
my @etimes = split(':', $event);
my $diff = $ctimes[0] - $etimes[0];

if($diff == 4) {
    print "New York\n";
} elsif($diff == 5) {
    print "Chicago\n";
} elsif($diff == 6) {
    print "Denver\n";
} else {
    print "could not determine timezone";
}
```

In Python it could be something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from datetime import timedelta

with open('f.txt') as f:
    l = f.readline()
f.close()

times = [s for s in l.split(',') if '_dt' in s]
ctimes = ((times[0]).split('=')[1]).strip().split(':')
etimes = ((times[1]).split('=')[1]).strip().split(':')

t1 = timedelta(hours=int(ctimes[0]), minutes=int(ctimes[1]), seconds=int(ctimes[2]))
t2 = timedelta(hours=int(etimes[0]), minutes=int(etimes[1]), seconds=int(etimes[2]))

diff = ((t1 - t2).seconds//3600)

if diff == 4:
    print("New York")
elif diff == 5:
    print("Chicago")
elif diff == 6:
    print("Denver")
```

Comment: Note: what I have above will not work now that you have reformatted your input. It should give you an idea of what to do, though.